# First Input Delay and Interaction to Next Paint showing N/A in the google pagespeed

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals, interaction-to-next-paint

I am checking my website on google PageSpeed and getting 97 scores. Also, core web vitals is also showing passed.

But why I am getting **First Input Delay** and **Interaction to Next Paint** N/A?

Is there any issue with my code or do I have to change some settings?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not all pages will have any interaction from users. For example a simple blog site, may just have readers who open the article, scroll (which doesn't count toward FID nor INP) to read the page, and then leave the page happy.

FID and INP are therefore optional in terms of Core Web Vitals - as you say your Core Web Vitals Assessment still says: Pass.